# Wrong sorting a text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

I have this simple text file and want to sort all lines by the `response_time` column:

```
1 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,507:INFO :pool-8982-thread-30:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==43975&items, response_time=1030, response_code=300 
2 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,628:INFO :pool-8982-thread-77:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==PBD4766&items, response_time=1142, response_code=200 
3 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,651:INFO :pool-8982-thread-67:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==MDC1810C&items, response_time=1166, response_code=200 
4 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,655:INFO :pool-8984-thread-47:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1031086&items, response_time=1005, response_code=200 
5 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,668:INFO :pool-8984-thread-50:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==F1018P&items, response_time=1018, response_code=200 
6 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,677:INFO :pool-8983-thread-86:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==V2581261&items, response_time=1060, response_code=200 
7 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,681:INFO :pool-8982-thread-68:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==202581&items, response_time=1196, response_code=200 
8 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,686:INFO :pool-8984-thread-46:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1563200600&, response_time=1036, response_code=200 
9 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,693:INFO :pool-8983-thread-29:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==8DB355025371, response_time=1207, response_code=200
```

I tried it this way:

```
sort -n -t " " -k 8 myfile.txt
```

But I still got an unsorted file. Why?

**UPD:**
Time can be less than 1000 and more than 9999:

```
1 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,507:INFO :pool-8982-thread-30:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==43975&items, response_time=11030, response_code=300 
2 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,628:INFO :pool-8982-thread-77:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==PBD4766&items, response_time=1142, response_code=200 
3 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,651:INFO :pool-8982-thread-67:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==MDC1810C&items, response_time=1166, response_code=200 
4 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,655:INFO :pool-8984-thread-47:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1031086&items, response_time=1005, response_code=200 
5 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,668:INFO :pool-8984-thread-50:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==F1018P&items, response_time=1018, response_code=200 
6 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,677:INFO :pool-8983-thread-86:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==V2581261&items, response_time=1060, response_code=200 
7 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,681:INFO :pool-8982-thread-68:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==202581&items, response_time=1196, response_code=200 
8 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,686:INFO :pool-8984-thread-46:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1563200600&, response_time=1036, response_code=200 
9 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,693:INFO :pool-8983-thread-29:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==8DB355025371, response_time=7, response_code=200
```

**UPD2:**
I'm reduce parameter `uri`. It can contain different numbers of "=".

Comment: you didn't save it anywhere ... route to a file if you want it saved..  the output of the sort would have scrolled up your screen (which was your result)

Comment: @guiverc, what's the changed if I redirect output to file?

Comment: yep..  or use `tee` to still have your sorted-output on screen, plus allow saving a copy to a file.

Comment: @guiverc, I think you are mistaked.

Comment: sort -(params) file_to_sort.txt | tee file_sorted.txt

Answer (score 0):

As there's nothing in the way just drop the `-n` as well as the `-t` option:

```
sort -k 8 myfile.txt
```

---

If you however want to know why your way failed, let's `--debug`:

```
> sort -n -t " " -k 8 --debug myfile.txt
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
1 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,507:INFO :pool-8982-thread-30:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==43975&items, response_time=1030, response_code=300 
                                                                                                                                          ^ no match for key
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
… … …
```

It shows there's something wrong with your `KEYDEF`:

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where
>   F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are
>   origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from
>   the beginning
>          of  the  preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global
>   ordering options for that
>          key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.  Use --debug to diagnose incorrect key usage.

For your case this would be the right one:

```
sort -n -t " " -k 8.15,8.19 myfile.txt
```

Comment: dessert, you way do not works correctly, because time can be not exactly with 4 digits.

Comment: @YShinkarev Why didn't you say that? The only thing you need to change is the `KEYDEF`, for which I gave instructions – e.g. `-k 8.15,8.19` for 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` takes as a delimiter whatever you give it, so just give it the right thing:

```
sort -n -t "=" -k5
```

sort numerically after the fourth `=`.

Comment: I'm reduce uri line, it can contain different numbers of "=" :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -k8V ex.txt
```

where

- `-k8V` means: key is the 8.th field, and order criteria is "version sort"

Version sort is the most natural sort -- uses alphabetic sort for letters but switches to numeric sort when number appears (it works both for numbers, words, and mixed)

Answer (score -1):

`sort -t " " -k 8 myfile.txt` outputs to the terminal the desired result. You don't need to use `-n` parameter because the field you want to sort by doesn't contain only digits.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why my answer was downvoted?